# Ajax request won't work on page load and then refresh, but will work after clicking link to the same page

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a site.com/ and e-shop on site.com/b2b/ (site.com/b2b/index.php)

Products are listed on  e-shop and if I click a button Add to Cart on any product, buttons text changes to Added and AJAX request sends data and updates Shopping Cart.

Now here is my problem.

If I close the browser, reopen it, start it in Incognito Mode (I can reproduce without IM, but just to be extra sure) and go directly to site.com/b2b/ in the URL bar, EVERYTHING works correctly.

But,

if I close the browser, reopen it, start it in Incognito Mode, go to site.com, and then click a link to site.com/b2b/, clicking the button Add to Cart on any product, changes the button text to Added and it visually updates the Shopping Cart to Amount of products is 1 and temporarily adds text Product Added to Cart, but the price is still 0.00.

Then if I add another product by clicking Add to Cart, it again visually updates Shopping Cart along with the temporary text, but the amount of products is still 1 and price is still 0.00.

Regardless of this last step, if I refresh the page, the Shopping Cart is empty and button texts on product are reseted to Add to Cart.

Now the horcrux of the whole story (sorry for being so verbose).

If I click the on-site link to the same URL (site.com/b2b/), which is visually the same as refreshing the page, but SOMETHING MUST HAPPEN in the back, then (of course Shopping Cart is still empty, but) EVERYTHING WORKS NORMALLY AGAIN.

I can add product and they are saved in Shopping Cart even after refresh or clicking any links the same site or any other site in the same site.com/b2b/ directory.

If anyone has ANY insight, I would be immensely grateful.

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done and what code are you using?

Comment: I think it may be related to the start of your session. Clicking on the link must trigger some method on your code that refreshing is not seeing it. Can you share some code with us?

Comment: Can you please show some code mate :) Will make it easier for the community to help you

Comment: Sorry guys, back then I just started out and had no clue about anything (even using SO), though I thought I knew something. I didn't even solve the problem but worked around it so it didn't matter. No longer have the code